# Flink Left-Outer-JOIN: Enriching a Stream with Data from a csv file

Tags: java, left-join, flink-streaming

I am using Flink `1.4.0`.

I am consuming data from a Kafka Topic into a DataStream. The data is transformed into a `POJO`, say `Employee`,  and I end up with a something like:

```
DataStream<Employee> employeeStream = ...;
```

Now, I need to enrich some fields in the instances of this stream using data from a big `csv` file. I found a nice way to load the csv and create a another DataStream:

```
DataStream<Enrichements> enrichmentsStream = ...;
```

Now, both `POJOs` share one field (id) which can be used for a `JOIN` operation. If these were DataSets, I would have been able to apply a `leftOuterJoin()`, but they are not. I don't care about windowing, as I want any `Employee` to be enriched with information from `Enrichments`, if its id is present in the csv. How do I do this? Would a join operation that ignores windowing work? Would it be resource hungry? Would it look like this?:

```
    employeeStream 
        .join(enrichmentsStream )
        .where(new SelectKeyForEmployee())
        .equalTo(new SelectKeyForEnrichments())
        .window(?????)
        .apply(new JoinEnrichFunction());
```

Also, since the window has to be shared by the two streams, how do I define their windowing prior to applying the `JOIN` function and what would be the implementation of the `JoinEnrichFunction()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that a join operation is redundant in this case. Stream joins are not intuitive and they make sense only when applied between streams that share the same windowing mechanisms.

In this case, a map function is more than enough to satisfy the enrichment objective detailed here. The following snippet of code should be clarifying enough:

```
public MainClass {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    // Some custom way of loading the csv data into a Map<POJO> format
    MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader("pathToData.csv");
    Map<Employee> metadataHashMap = loader.getMetadataMap(employeeEnrichmentData);
    ...

    // Enrichment
    SingleOutputStreamOperator<Employee>> enrichedStream = rawStream
            .map(new MapMetadataToEmployees(metadataHashMap))
            .name("Enrich: with Employee Metadata");

    // Some sink opeartion
    ...

  }
}  

final class MapMetadataToEmployees implements MapFunction<Employee, Employee>, Serializable {

  private Map<Employee> metaDataMap;

  public MapMetadataToEmployees(Map<String, Employee> metaDataMap) {
      this.metaDataMap = metaDataMap;
  }

  @Override
  public Employee map(Employee employee) {

      if (metaDataMap.containsKey(employee.getId())) {

          Employee employeeWithMetaData = metaDataMap.get(employee.getId());

          employee.setSalary(employeeWithMetaData.getSalary);
          employee.setRank(employeeWithMetaData.getRank());
          employee.setBusinessTitle(employeeWithMetaData.getBusinessTitle());
      }

      return employee;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I do have 2 questions though:

1. Flink supports parallelism. What happens if your stream is running on multiple machines? Will your map reside in memory on every Flink worker?

2. What happens when you want to update your CSV file and reload that data (but not miss messages from your stream while the MetadataLoader works).
Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: As per 1: The constructor of the `MapMetadataToEmployees` is called with a `metaDataMap` instance. So yes, that is exactly what will happen. So, yes, the `metaDataMap` will reside in the memory of each worker since every instance of the `MapMetadataToEmployees` used by each worker is instantiated with it (the `metaDataMap`). 
2 now is much more complex. The answer to that question is very similar to what needs to happen in the case of model serving. Have a look at this FLIP over here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-23+-+Model+Serving. HTH